# Overlapping match statements in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm currently working on a homework assignment. Essentially it's a very basic version of symbolic math. The following snippet of code works perfectly fine.

```
let rec eval exp (vars:(string * int) list) = match exp with
    | Int n -> n
    | Plus (a, b) -> (eval a vars) + (eval b vars)
    (* ... more match statements ... *)
```

For example if I enter in "eval (Plus (Int 3) (Int 5)) []" it properly returns 8. However when I try to add a "let" expression it gives an error. Here is a snippet of my modified eval function:

```
(* either returns Some value or None *)
let rec findVar key l = ...

let rec eval exp (vars:(string * int) list) = match exp with
    | Id id -> match (findVar id vars) with
        | Some value -> value
        | None -> raise (Failure ("Unknown variable " ^ id))
    | Int n -> n
    | Plus (a, b) -> (eval a vars) + (eval b vars)
    (* ... more match statements ... *)

(* raises "Error: The variant type option has no constructor Int" *)
```

I believe the reason is that the compiler sees the code as:

```
let rec eval exp (vars:(string * int) list) = match exp with
    | Id id -> match (findVar id vars) with
        | Some value -> value
        | None -> raise (Failure ("Unknown variable " ^ id))
        | Int n -> n
        | Plus (a, b) -> (eval a vars) + (eval b vars)
        (* ... more match statements ... *)
```

If my intuition is right that this is the error, how do I fix it?

If there's another cause for my error, what is it?

Comment: See [here][1]; first answer on Google.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257605/ocaml-match-expression-inside-another-one

Comment: You are correct, you must wrap your inner match expression with parens or begin-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should either delimit your inner matches with parens (or their syntactic equivalents `begin/end`), or to factor your code into separate helper functions. I definitely prefer the latter.

```
let rec eval exp (vars : (string * int) list) = match exp with
    | Id id -> eval_var vars id
    | Int n -> n
    | Plus (a, b) -> (eval a vars) + (eval b vars)
    (* ... more match statements ... *)
 and eval_var vars id = match findVar id vars with
    | Some v -> ...
```